# Prove common ratio of GP from a equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics, geometric-progressions

If $(a²+b²)x²-2b(c+a)(b/a)x+(b²+c²)=0$ has equal roots, how do I prove that $a$, $b$, $c$ are in G.P. and their common ratio is $x$.

Since the roots are equal

$D=b²-4ac=0$

I've put the values and I get

$b=√(ac)$

which means that $a$, $b$, $c$ are in G.P. But how do prove that $x$ is the common ratio?

Comment: It's unfortunate that "a", "b", and "c" are used here since they are NOT the "a", "b", and "c" in the quadratic formula!  You have that the geometric progression is $a, \sqrt{ab}, b$.  The "common ratio" is $\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{a}= \frac{b}{\sqrt{ab}}= \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$.  You have already used the fact that, in the quadratic formula,"$b^2- 4ac= 0$.  Do the rest- since the root is 0, the quadratic formula gives $x= \frac{-b}{2a}4$ (for $ax^2+ bx+ c= 0$) which here would be $\frac{2b^2(c+ a)}{a(a^2+ B^2)}$

Answer (score 1):

Let r be the common ratio. Then, $r^2 = \dfrac ca$.

Also, if $\alpha$ is a root, then $\alpha^2 =$ the product of the roots $= \dfrac {b^2 + c^2}{a^2 + b^2}$. The last fraction can be converted to $\dfrac ca$ through substitution of $b^2$ by $ca$ and cancellations.

Therefore, $r^2 = \alpha^2$.